# .remove is not function How to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

```
var dbRefObjectHis = firebase.database().ref('Box1').child('history');
dbRefObjectHis.on('value',gotData, errData);

function gotData(data) {
    var ref = d3.selectAll('.His');
    for (var i = 0; i < ref.length; i++){
    ref[i].remove();
}

var history = data.val();
var keys = Object.keys(history);

for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    var humidity = history[k].humidity;
    var temperature = history[k].temperature;

    $('.His').append('Humidity:' + humidity + 'Temperature:' + temperature  );

}
```

Comment: When you remove refs[0], refs[1] becomes refs[0], but you still try to remove refs[1] next (etc).

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing bracket in the `gotData` loop.

Comment: how to fix? do you have code fixed

Comment: Can someone help me T.T

Comment: is that jquery remove function?  if so, you need to do it on a jquery object: `$(ref[i]).remove();`  But if you want more help: please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to replicate your issue - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the element you are trying to remove is not a removable Node.

try replacing

```
for (var i = 0; i < ref.length; i++){
    ref[i].remove();
}
```

with

```
ref.forEach(function(e) {
    e.remove();
});
```

Comment: Please help me T.T

Comment: I was a bit to fast in my response. This are d3 elements and not Nods.

try this:
ref.forEach(function(e) {
    e.html(null);
});